# PostgreSQL: Information about sources (for a View)

Tags: postgresql, view, dbeaver

I have a VIEW which is huge. Lots of tables, other views and CASE WHENs feed this view.
I would like to make sense of it, so I figured I could write some statement in order to get a table-like output with sources for all columns within this VIEW. Unfortunately, I don't know exactly how to do this (as for some columns there are multiple sources).
Also, would it be possible to have this also in a diagram-type drawing?
I know i can select multiple tables and then get a diagram with connections between them, but what about different sources for the columns within this VIEW?

I would even appreciate any other way to approach this.
I got this task to write down all sources for all columns and try figure out which ones (tables/or calculated fields) are no longer working for the VIEW. Unfortunately, very few tables have a "last_updated" column so there is no way for me to find out if/when they got last updated.
I figured out, I could make an inventory first, and then go through all departments tracking down who works on what.

I use Dbeaver for Postgres databases (if that matters)

Comment: From here [Info functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html): `pg_get_viewdef ( view oid [, pretty boolean ] )`. So `select pg_get_viewdef ('some_view'::regclass, true);`

Comment: I have access to source code. My question is: about making a summary/inventory of sources used by that view (IF possible).